# Do we support questions about virtual machines?

Tags: discussion

I've done a fair amount of research trying to help users with questions about VirtualBox but the vast majority of what I've found instructs simply to install guest additions and pray. Other commenters say that elementary OS is not designed to work with emulated hardware and to just not bother. I don't know if there is an official stance on virtual machine support—I imagine, more likely, is that everyone tries to help where they can but that there is a noted lack of bandwidth for virtual machine issues—but what is our stance?

When questions are about hardware emulation in virtual machines, how should we respond, given how they're de facto unsupported in Launchpad?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is a good question. My personal feeling is that "install guest additions and pray" is the best it's gonna get. Without hardware acceleration, there's going to be issues and you'll never get native performance just by definition. Unsure what the best way to present it is, but that's just my thoughts.